# Rails: Association works with User but not current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm having a strange issue.

I have a number of models and associations that work perfectly together but when I try to introduce the current_user I get:

**ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError at /dashboard
Message Association named 'game' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?**

Here's some code that works:

**Controller:**

```
  def index 
    users = current_user.followed_users.collect { |user| user.id }
    @userupdates    = Userupdate.for_users(users, params[:page])
  end
```

**View:**

```
   <% @userupdates.each do |userupdate| %>
    Things and stuff
   <% end %>
```

But when I try to make the page display content from followed_users AND the current_user like so..

```
def index 
   users = current_user.followed_users.collect { |user| user.id }
   users.push(current_user.id)
   @userupdates    = Userupdate.for_users(users, params[:page])
end
```

...I get the error above.

Some of the relavent  model code:

```
class Userupdate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userupdates

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userupdates
```

Comment: where is the Game model???

Comment: @bjhaid added..not sure how it didn't get pasted..

Comment: do you run your migrations and does userupdate have a game_id column?

Comment: can you show your `Userupdate.for_users` method?

Comment: @ifyouseewendy   def self.for_users(users, page = 1, per = 10)
    Userupdate.where("user_id in (?)", users).order("created_at desc").includes([:game, :user]).page(page).per(per)
  end

Comment: @bjhaid Yeah, column is there in the DB.

Comment: @ClaytonCorreia I think you are using includes wrongly... or you have set up your association wrongly either of the 2

Comment: As an aside, on your index action you'd be better off using the `pluck` method instead of `collect`.  e.g. `users = current_user.followed_users.pluck(:id)`.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError` is explained as below in rails [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/ConfigurationError.html).

> Raised when association is being configured improperly or user tries to use offset and limit together with has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many associations.

So I thought the problem is your association configured. You may check again the association, like whether model `Userupdate` has `user_id` and `game_id`.

And the `current_user` issue, maybe you should check your query sql to see whether your `includes` works. If works, it should do the outer join between `userupdates` and `users`, `userupdates` and `games`, and you'll see loading `users` and `games` after loading `userupdates` in log. And `current_user` maybe the only user who has the `userupdates` whose belonging `game` exists.

All my opinions, hope this can help.